# How do you beat the Developer in candy box 2?

Tags: candy-box-2

In Candy box 2, how do you beat the developer. I have the pink gloves, the knight Armour, the scythe, I think I don't have enough health. I have 1560 and when I eat candies it doesn't go any higher, I've eaten over 8,000,000 candies and I have the necklace. Is there another way to increase your health or a different way to defeat the developer. And i'm using berserk potions it's just not working.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Arqade! Could you explain your question in more detail? We could help you better if we knew your tactic for fighting the boss.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to beat him using the Giant Spoon of Doom (with double damage from claw) and two berserk potions. Drink the first one as soon as you get into melee range, drink the second one as soon as the first one wears off. Done right you should beat him just before the second wave of words hits you. With 1560 health and the knight armor (30%) you should be able to survive the first wave of words without having to use a health potion.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use a turtle potion while you are close to him and when he attacks you (right when he hits you) use erase magic (It worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you have 1560 health. What did you use your Pains au chocolat on? You can use those to increase your max health.

Here's my build to beat the developer:

[image: screenshot]

(The hat doesn't matter. I just use Merchant's hat for max candy. You can choose what boots you want to use, as those don't really change anything.)

Anyway, after you start the developer fight try to get as much damage in before "I'm glad you got here" causes that's basically an instant kill.

After you get around a quarter of his health, use the spell "black demons". This is usually what happens if you do:

[image: screenshot]